# Top and bottom layout does not work as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two view in a vertical orientated `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:text="dddd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/below"
            android:layout_below="@id/top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#33000000"
                android:textColor="#80000000"
                android:id="@+id/copy_right"
                android:text="Copyright @2013"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

While I want the `bottom` view with a `wrap_content` height, then the `top` take all the left space.

But it does not work.

What's the problem? Anyone can help me to fix it?

---

BTW, this is an alternative method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
                android:text="dddd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/below"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0">

        <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#33000000"
                android:textColor="#80000000"
                android:id="@+id/copy_right"
                android:text="Copyright @2013"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It meet my requirement, but I do not want make the `bottom` view with a fixed height.

Comment: Let me redesign it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplified layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/copy_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#33000000"
        android:textColor="#80000000"
        android:text="Copyright @2013"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/copy_right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dddd"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am afraid I can not simplify it since I have other view in the `top` and `bottom` container.:(

Comment: It's not shown in your original layout... If you repost your layout including all the views, I can remake it. Where is the other view? where should it go?

Comment: I tried to add them later...  This is the final effect I want :http://pbrd.co/1pmYgN7  In fact, they other views are inside the `top`,and there may be more views to be added later.

Comment: I edited the layout as per new specifications. Now the top part is a RelativeLayout container, allowing you to add the extra controls.

Comment: BTW, I can not see any difference between yours and my original solution, what is the problem?

Comment: `I can not see any difference between yours and my original solution` - **1**. I'm not using an useless outer container for the TextView **2**. My TextView is declared AFTER the RelativeLayout containing the extra controls. **3** I take advantage of the alignParentTop and alignParentBottom attributes. There are many other subtle differences you might want to discover yourself. ;)

Comment: I am sorry I missed that. BTW, I found an interesting point, the `TextView` is defined before the `top` container, I tried to exchange them(use `layout_below` instead of `layout_above`), then it does not work, what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, at least part of it. It must be defined before, so that it exists when it's referenced by the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can set weight on top layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:text="dddd"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/below"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/copy_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#33000000"
            android:text="Copyright @2013"
            android:textColor="#80000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: now you can try ,I have just edited,there    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"